# How can I add space character only to the first & last column and row in an two dimensional array?

Tags: c++

I have probably a simple problem,
this is what i get:
[image: output]

My point is to have a table which contains space character in the first and the last column and in the first and the last row, and in all other places the random value which is "o" or space character. 
Also, I want to "close" this board with the mark of "|" at the end of every row, just to make it look neat.

In function generujpole there are 4 lines (e.g. pole[i][0] = ' ';) which I thought would solve the problem, but it didn't work for the last column.

What is wrong and how should it be written properly?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int width = 62;
const int height = 22;

void generujpole(char pole[][height])
{
for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
{
for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
{
pole[i][0] = ' ';
pole[i][61]= ' ';
pole[0][j] = ' ';
pole[21][j] = ' ';

int maluj = rand()%100;
if(maluj < 90) pole[i][j] = ' ';
else pole[i][j] = 'o';
}
}
}

void wypiszpole(char pole[][height])
{
cout <<endl;
cout<< "                       GAME OF LIFE";
cout << endl << endl;
cout << "+------------------------------------------------------------+" 
<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
cout << "|";
for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
{
cout << pole[i][j];
}
cout << "|" << endl;
}
cout << "+------------------------------------------------------------+"<<endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "      R - reset,     Q - quit,     K - step    " << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post links to external resources. They might go down in the future making the resources inaccessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two `'-'`s to your top and bottom bars, e.g.:

```
cout << "+--------------------------------------------------------------+"
```

instead of

```
cout << "+------------------------------------------------------------+"
```

But it seems short-sighted design to hard-code all of this. You may wish to change the size in the future, at which time you'd have to re-write much of your code.

Consider starting to approach design dynamically by drawing these bars with:

```
cout << '+';

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) 
{
    cout << '-';
}

cout << '+' << endl;
```

As for border spacing along the right edge, it seems you're combining your border-printing desires with grid-generating logic. Keep the two separate: if you wish to have a border at the beginning and end of each row, print an extra space in `wypiszpole` rather than attempting to manipulate the game grid by hand (again using hard-coded values) in `generujpole`. Assuming this is [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), you'll be overwriting these "border" elements after an iteration or using roundabout logic to avoid doing so.

Additionally, it's easy to get `width` and `height` mixed up: generally, the outer array is the `height` and the inner array is the `width`. Your code confuses the two, using `width` as the outer loop in `wypiszpole` but `height` as the outer loop in `generujpole`.

Below is a full example to illustrate the above points. Try changing `height` and `width` to see how it responds.

As a final note, you may consider using vectors and classes; this will improve encapsulation of functions and abstract away many array size and memory management concerns.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void generujpole(int width, int height, char **pole)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            pole[i][j] = rand() % 100 < 90 ? ' ' : 'o';
        }
    }
}

void wypiszpole(int width, int height, char **pole)
{
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - 4; i++) 
    { 
        cout << ' '; 
    }

    cout << "GAME OF LIFE";
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << '+';

    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++) 
    { 
        cout << '-'; 
    }

    cout << '+' << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        cout << "| ";

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            cout << pole[i][j];
        }

        cout << " |" << endl;
    }

    cout << '+';

    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++) 
    { 
        cout << '-'; 
    }

    cout << '+' << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - 17; i++) 
    { 
        cout << ' '; 
    }

    cout << "R - reset,     Q - quit,     K - step" << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    const int width = 40;
    const int height = 15;
    char** pole = new char*[height];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 
    {
        pole[i] = new char[width];
    }

    generujpole(width, height, pole);
    wypiszpole(width, height, pole);

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 
    {
        delete[] pole[i];
    }

    delete[] pole;
    return 0;
}
```

Output for a few example dimensions:

```
  GAME OF LIFE

+--------------+
|     o  o     |
| o            |
|              |
| o         o  |
+--------------+

R - reset,     Q - quit,     K - step
```

```
                GAME OF LIFE

+------------------------------------------+
|     o  o    o                       o    |
|       o     o     o            o         |
|          o        o o     o  o           |
|     o       o                   o        |
|       o        o             o   o       |
|                o    oo   o        o      |
|   o                              o       |
|    o  o oo    oo    o                    |
|        o                o   o      o  o  |
| oo o      o           o                  |
|      o        o        o o   o o   o     |
|             ooo              o           |
|         oo   o              o o   o      |
|        o     o     o       o             |
|                                       o  |
+------------------------------------------+

   R - reset,     Q - quit,     K - step
```

```
                                    GAME OF LIFE

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     o  o    o                       o         o     o     o            o         |
|          o        o o     o  o              o       o                   o        |
|       o        o             o   o                     o    oo   o        o      |
|   o                              o         o  o oo    oo    o                    |
|        o                o   o      o  o oo o      o           o                  |
|      o        o        o o   o o   o                ooo              o           |
|         oo   o              o o   o            o     o     o       o             |
|                                       o  o     o     ooo     o        o       o  |
|                   o             o     o       o  o              o    o     o     |
|   o                 o       o          o          o                 o            |
|                     o    oo o                               o     o         o    |
| o o       oo o                  o     o    o                     o         o  o  |
| o o    o       o o       o o      o     o                 o       o o         o  |
|                                           oo       o   o   o             o       |
|                       o                  oo      o      o                 o    o |
|  o        oo              o o                                  o                 |
|       o             o      o   o      o               o  o          o      o     |
| o o       oo            o                       o  o     o   o  oo          o o  |
|                    o          o          o  o    oo     o     o          o     o |
|          o       o o              o       o             o         oo             |
|   o  o                 o       o        o o   oo                o        o       |
| o       o    o     o     oo                        o       o         o       oo  |
|             o                   o    o               o   o                       |
|             o   o          o       o            o      o  o      o     o         |
|     o o                 o  o           o     o          o                        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

                       R - reset,     Q - quit,     K - step
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/ElectronicAllDatalogs)

Comment: Thank you, but the last column isn't empty still. Do you know what else is wrong?

Comment: Take a look at my update and let me know if I'm missing any additional concerns.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's really helpful, it simplified what I've already had. The problem is that I do not use pointers and dynamic arrays yet so this is quite confusing for me. Is there a way to do this without this? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, you can always hard-code the dimensions, use the first part of my answer and the added spaces in the printing routine and keep the dynamic memory stuff in mind for the future. Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@obeeey: In your function *generujpol*, you have to split the *for loo* into two separate loops as follow:

```
// We fill the first and last rows with 'space' character
for(int i=0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
{
    pole[0][i] = ' ';
    pole[width-1][i] = ' ';
}
//Now, we fill the first and last column with 'space character
for(int i=0; i < width; i++)
{
    pole[i][0] = ' ';
    pole[i][height-1] = ' ';
}
```

An appropriate way to have a line filled with '+-----+' is to proceed as follow:

```
 // Create a string of length 'height' filled with '-'
 string line(height, '-');
 // then add '+' at the back and front
 line = "+" + line + "+";
 // now you can comfortably write.
 cout << line << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a simple solution for those lines, really helpful. Unfortunalety, adding two for loops didn't help or I'm doing this wrong. Could you expand this idea? How should I connect those loops with the random values?

Comment: Update: I've added those two loops in function generujpole after loop generating random values to the array and now it works perfectly.